# sympy nsolve typeError with Matrix starting vector

Tags: matrix, typeerror, sympy, solver

I'm getting a `TypeError` with `nsolve` when I give it a `Matrix` for the starting vector. Notably, `nsolve` is perfectly fine with the fact that the equation is a `Matrix` expression. Here's a basic example:

```
import sympy as sy
v = sy.Matrix(sy.symarray("v", (2,)))
w = sy.Matrix([17, 23])
equation = v - w
```

The following line gives a `TypeError: cannot create mpf from Matrix([[17],[23]])`:

```
sy.nsolve(equation, v, w)
```

The following line is a kludgy workaround which gives the correct output, `Matrix([[17.0],[23.0]])`:

```
sy.nsolve(equation, v, w.T.tolist()[0])
```

Is there a better solution than this workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround you have is necessary, given the following:

1. `nsolve` passes the `x0` argument directly to `mpmath.findroot`, on [this line](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/solvers/solvers.py#L2919)
2. `findroot` only supports iterables in `x0` that satisfy `isinstance(x0, (list, tuple))`, on [this line](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath/blob/dcba1419b85304f2396910dbdc5e60af77ecc27a/mpmath/calculus/optimization.py#L908). Moreover it has to be a flat tuple or list; its elements are assumed to be scalars in the subsequent `x0 = [ctx.convert(x) for x in x0]`.

A SymPy matrix is not an instance of either `list` or `tuple`. Also, `w.tolist()` is not enough because the resulting list is nested. Hence the need for `w.T.tolist()[0]`.

---

This is now  [an open issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/14950) in SymPy repo.

Comment: Thanks, I've opened the issue [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/14950).